# `canInitWithRequest` not called in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, xcode15, ohhttpstubs

We're currently using `PINRemoteImage` as an image loader and also `OHHTTPStubs` to mock network requests for testing. All of this was working perfectly fine in Xcode 14, but image stubbing fails to work in Xcode 15.

I've checked and all other stubbing in Xcode 15, and all bog standard network requests where we just use `NSURLSession` are still able to be stubbed no problem.

On digging in a little, we found that the function `+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;` in `NSURLProtocol` is no longer called by `PINRemoteImage` when it's loading an image in Xcode 15, but it is in Xcode 14. This is a critical step in being able to stub network requests as it's how `OHHTTPStubs` gets setup.

I've posted on both the repos for `PINRemoteImage` and `OHHTTPStubs` but I'm not hopeful about getting a response.

I'm curious to see if anyone knows of any underlying changes made to `NSURLSession` with Xcode 15 that would cause this effect?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: _I'm curious to see if anyone knows of any underlying changes made to NSURLSession with Xcode 15 that would cause this effect?_ No. We use a URLProtocol subclass all day every day for testing, and I can assure you that `canInit` is called.

Comment: Are you sure the protocol is registered in the session that is being used by that class?